# How to set a label equal to a textbox, with every letter on a separate line?

Tags: c#, button, textbox, label

So I have this label, textbox and button, all in this in the Connect Four game that I'm programming.

My goal is to have the player enter their name in the textbox, then click the button, and have the label equal the word in the textbox, but with each letter of the word being on a different line in the label.

So how do I do this?

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: Is this XNA or Winforms or what?

Comment: This is not XNA, it's just regular old C#, and I'm using the Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition to program it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
        label1.Text = String.Empty;

        foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
        {
            label1.Text += c + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: Your code is funny, it does both. It displays the contents of the textbox both horizontally and vertically in the label, lol

Comment: Not too clear on exactly what you want to do...but I'm sure you can modify this. If you need to clear the label text first, or clear the textbox first, this should be intuitive.

Comment: I want the player to enter their name in the textbox, then click the button, and have the label equal the word in the textbox, but with each letter of the word being on a different line in the label, rather than having the word just be in the normal horizontal format, so it'd be read vertically instead.

Comment: Your code has it do both in the label: display the word horizontally and vertically

Comment: Updated the code. Label's text is cleared -> textbox's text is vertically appended, one character at a time, to the label.

Comment: It works, thank you, but could you just tell me what exactly it means when it says String.Empty ?

Comment: Are you looking up these things before asking? First link on google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx ... "In application code, this field is most commonly used in assignments to initialize a string variable to an empty string."

It's the equivalent of label1.Text = "", but it's cleaner to read.

Comment: I didn't even think of looking up String.Empty on Google since I wasn't able to find the answer to my question on Google, I got it